# How can I configure Flow to show all errors via .flowconfig?

Tags: flowtype

I know I can use `--show-all-errors` from CLI, but to make it work with ALE and Neovim, I'd like to add this option in .flowconfig file, too. Possible?

Related ALE configuration for Flow: https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/ale_linters/javascript/flow.vim

Comment: I *thought* you could set `max_warnings = 1000` (or whatever) under `[options]` , but it doesn't appear in the documentation (https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/). Maybe worth a try?